# Web pop up wont show after implementing cookies via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I recently was given a solution to checking if a pop up has been shown and then only showing it once using cookies. But after implementing cookies the pop up no longer shows. I have googled the issue, and tried to find a solution but my lack of knowledge on the subject has made it difficult for me to understand the issue and fix it.

This is the code i am using, i have implemented the use of cookies and i believe that they should work but the pop up however is not working

```js
function setCookie(cname,cvalue) {
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var user=getCookie("ageverification");
  if (user != "") {
    return null;
  } else {
    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    overlay.show();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    $('.popup').show();
    $('.close').click(function() {
      $('.popup').hide();
      overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
      return false;
      user = true;      
      setCookie("ageverification", user);
    });
  }
}

function goBack() {
  window.history.go(-2);
}
```

```html
<div class='popup'>
  <div class='cnt223'>
  <h1>Important Notice</h1>
  <p>
    You must be over 18 to Purchase products on this website!
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href='' class='close' style="color:green">I Am Over 18</a>
    <a href='' class='goBack()' style="color:red">I Am Not</a>
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A little piece of advice, regardless of the overall answer. You can simplify your code and remove this code: `while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {c = c.substring(1);}` by using the trim method in the subsequent if, which would become `if (c.trim().indexOf(name) == 0)`. The trim method, called on a string, will remove preceding and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Also, your checkCookie function has 2 lines of code that will never be run because they are written after a return statement: `user = true;` and `setCookie("ageverification", user);`.

Comment: @roccobarbi thank you i will have a look at simplifying the code, also thank you for pointing that out i never realised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied some changes to your code and now it should work.

As a summary, I applied these changes:

- removed dead code from checkCookie;
- simplified the code for getCookie;
- eliminated the overlay div (which did nothing: it was just created empty, attached to the DOM and then removed from it);
- changed "popup" from a class to an id;
- made the selector strings more specific.

To improve the getCookie function, I eliminated an unnecessary loop and a few substrings. You can get to the same result more cleanly using the trim method (which eliminates preceding and trailing whitespace from a string) and splitting the cookie by "=".

To improve checkCookie, I eliminated some dead code (which couldn't run because it was after a return statement), some redundant one (which declared variables for values needed only once) and the apparently useless div tag. Also, I changed the selector strings to explicitly reference the "a" node inside the popup and I added a call to preventDefault(). This last part (changing the selector strings and calling preventDefault) was the one solving the issue.

```js
function setCookie(cname,cvalue) {
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var ca = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim().split('=');
        if (cname == c[0] && c.length > 1) {
            return c[1];
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  if (getCookie("ageverification") == ""){
        $('#popup').show();
        $('#popup a.close').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#popup').hide();
            setCookie("ageverification", 'true');
        });
        $('#popup a.goBack').click(function ( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            goBack();
        });
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function goBack() {
  window.history.go(-2);
}
```

```html
<div id='popup'>
  <div class='cnt223'>
  <h1>Important Notice</h1>
  <p>
    You must be over 18 to Purchase products on this website!
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href='' class='close' style="color:green">I Am Over 18</a>
    <a href='' class='goBack()' style="color:red">I Am Not</a>
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, i have attempted to run this instead of what i had wrote but the issue still stands. For some reason the Pop up refuses to show when i try to use cookies and have it show like this. Im completely stumped.

Comment: Well, is it possible that it depends on some other element that you didn't include in the question? I would bet on it: if you try to run the snippet, it displays the contents allright, so your issue probably depends on something else entirely.

Comment: as far as im aware, everything required for that snippet is included. The only other thing not included is the inline CSS for the webpage. I have even removed everything from the site completely and tried it which is why im so stumped

Comment: I had an intuition and now it should really work. The popup is set with an id, not a class. Moreover I specify that the click event is on '#popup a.close' and I call preventDefault on it.

Comment: Thank you, its a step in the right direction. Its showing above the page in the header now instead of popping up over the webpage. And it wont hide when the button is pressed but i think i can solve the appearance myself.

Comment: @SelectiveIntuition the appearence depends on the css, which is not part of the question. If you have trouble with it, I would say that it requires a differenct Stackoverflow question. :-) About this one, I tested my solution [here](http://en.barbinirocco.com/tests/popup-test.html) and it seems to work. The box appears when you open the page for the first time (not as a popup because there are no styles), then it disappears as you click OK and it does not reappear. If and only if you agree that this answers your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: By the way, I just changed the code to align it with the version linked above, which also implements the goBack function call.

Comment: Ok i see it works for you, but even on my page it wont remove the box at all it just refreshes the page. I think its probably a CSS Issue so thank you for your help